# Tensorflow Lite: No module named tf.contrib.lite

Tags: android, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I tried to convert my already existing frozen graph, which is saved in a .pb-file, with the following code (tf_lite_converter.py):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
import tensorflow as tf

from tf.contrib.lite import convert_savedmodel

convert_savedmodel.convert(
    saved_model_dir="/frozen_inference_graph.pb",
    output_tflite="/TF_Lite_Model")
```

When running the code with

```
python tf_lite_converter.py
```

in my anaconda environment, it gives me the error:

```
ImportError: No module named tf.contrib.lite
```

My goal is to get a tensorflowlite-model out of my .pb-graph to use it in an Android application. I already tried to build tflite with toco through bazel, but maybe (or most likely) I did something wrong or it was not the right way to fix the problem.

Referencing Video from Tensorflow-Developers:
https://youtu.be/FAMfy7izB6A?t=11m49s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code in that video is probably from an internal development version.

convert_savedmodel has been renamed to convert_saved_model in https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/commit/db076ca01f12368c9476fa4db9d87756f22f9670

The following seems to work for tensorflow 1.8:

```
from  tensorflow.contrib.lite.python import convert_saved_model

convert_saved_model.convert(saved_model_dir="/frozen_inference_graph.pb",output_tflite="/TF_Lite_Model")
```

The following is for tensorflow built from the current master (method and parameter have been renamed):

```
from  tensorflow.contrib.lite.python import convert_saved_model

convert_saved_model.tflite_from_saved_model(saved_model_dir="/frozen_inference_graph.pb",output_file="/TF_Lite_Model")
```

Comment: Now it gives me "Import Error: cannot import name convert_savedmodel" (or convert_saved_model). I am so confused '^^

Comment: note that it is `convert_saved_model`, not `convert_savedmodel`

Comment: Yeah I tried that as mentioned in the parentheses. Looks like a strange problem.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I had tested with tensorflow built from the master and they have already renamed things since 1.8 - I've edited the answer. If you still have problems, try to check the tensorflow version.

Comment: Ah well I reinstalled tensorflow, now it works. Thanks for your help! Maybe you also know why the convert method gives me the error "IOError: SavedModel file does not exist at: /frozen_inference_graph.pb". I am in the right directory and the pb-file exists. Stumbling from one error to the next ... grrr^^.

Comment: The parameter is called `saved_model_dir` and you have to pass the name of the directory (that contains the saved_model.pb). Also, a leading "/" means this is an absolute directory name.

Comment: I tested it with a folder that just contains the .pb file, nothing else. Also tested it with the checkpoint files and. Both did not work. What does the folder need to contain for convert to work?

Comment: See https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/saved_model#structure_of_a_savedmodel_directory

Answer (score 1):

None of the above things worked for me.

I downgraded to Tensorflow 1.7 and converted the .pb model to .tflite model using toco.

```
$ pip install --upgrade "tensorflow==1.7.*"

$ toco \
  --input_file=tf_files/retrained_graph.pb \
  --output_file=tf_files/optimized_graph.lite \
  --input_format=TENSORFLOW_GRAPHDEF \
  --output_format=TFLITE \
  --input_shape=1,${IMAGE_SIZE},${IMAGE_SIZE},3 \
  --input_array=input \
  --output_array=final_result \
  --inference_type=FLOAT \
  --input_data_type=FLOAT
```

Ref :
https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/tensorflow-for-poets-2-tflite/#2
https://github.com/googlecodelabs/tensorflow-for-poets-2/issues/52
https://medium.com/@rdeep/tensorflow-lite-tutorial-easy-implementation-in-android-145443ec3775

Comment: I tried that, but it gives me following error: Converting unsupported operation: TensorArraySizeV3

Comment: Someone said TensorflowLite does not support object detection, is that correct? https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/19078

Comment: Late comment, but no this is not correct. I managed to use it for Object Detection in the end.